# How do I append to a listbuffer which is a value of a mutable map in Scala?

Tags: scala

```
val mymap= collection.mutable.Map.empty[String,Seq[String]]
mymap("key") = collection.mutable.ListBuffer("a","b")
mymap.get("key") += "c"
```

The last line to append to the list buffer is giving error. How the append can be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deal with your problems one at a time:

1. `Map.get` returns an `Option[T]` and `Option` does not provide a `+=` or `+` method.
2. Even if you use `Map.apply` (`mymap("key")`) the return type of `apply` will be `V` (in this case `Seq`) regardless of what the actual concrete type is (`Vector`, `List`, `Set`, etc.). `Seq` does not provide a `+=` method, and its `+` method expects another `Seq`.

Given that, to get what you want you need to declare the type of the `Map` to be a mutable type:

```
import collection.mutable.ListBuffer
val mymap= collection.mutable.Map.empty[String,ListBuffer[String]]
mymap("key") = ListBuffer("a","b")
mymap("key") += "c"
```

will work as you expect it to.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the code in the scala console:

```
→$scala
scala> val mymap= collection.mutable.Map.empty[String,Seq[String]]
mymap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Seq[String]] = Map()

scala> mymap("key") = collection.mutable.ListBuffer("a","b")

scala> mymap.get("key")
res1: Option[Seq[String]] = Some(ListBuffer(a, b))
```

You'll see that `mymap.get("key")` is an optional type. You can't add a string to the optional type.

Additionally, since you typed `mymap` to `Seq[String]`, `Seq[String]` does not have a `+=` operator taking in a String.

The following works:

```
val mymap= collection.mutable.Map.empty[String,collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]]
mymap("key") = collection.mutable.ListBuffer("a","b")
mymap.get("key").map(_ += "c")
```

Using the `.map` function will take advantage of the optional type and prevent noSuchElementException as  Łukasz noted.

Comment: or `mymap.get("key").map(_ += "c")` to be safe from `NoSuchElementException`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have immutable value, then something like this should also work:

```
val mymap= collection.mutable.Map.empty[String,Seq[String]]
mymap("key") = Vector("a","b")
val oldValue = mymap.get("key").getOrElse(Vector[String]())
mymap("key") = oldValue :+ "c"
```

I used Vector here, because adding elements to the end of List is unefficient by design.